# Shortened unique url and path for assets

Tags: javascript, html, url, routes

How should I define my assets path when using shortened unique generated strings within the url, like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/GBK1TiRD
http://localhost:3000/URewrEc1
http://localhost:3000/MKwIUuKN
```

Each user session will have its dedicated urls like showed above.

The current path is below, and how I define it in the html:

```
<img src="assets/images/favourite.png" height="22" width="22"></img>
```

Obviously I will get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/GBK1TiRD/assets/images/favourite.png 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I define path for my assets dynamically when part of the string can be anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "hash"? No `.hash` appears at a URL at Question

Comment: Removed hash, maybe a bit misleading term in this context. Edited, get it now?

Comment: You could store the key, value pairs at a `JSON` formatted string and utilize `ServiceWorker` to respond with matched request